# How to block certain domains on a computer that is behind a proxy on which I have no control

Tags: windows, blocking

The situation:

- There is a windows 7 machine that can connect to internet only through an organisation's proxy.
- I have no control over the proxy servers.
- There is a single administrator account on the machine, and I do not wish to set up a limited account.

Question:

- How can certain domains be blocked, so that the user can not access them without some unblocking?
- The user is non technical and is not adamant, hence simple solutions should work effectively.

Issues:

- Hosts file doesn't work since all requests are routed through proxy server.
- Configuring the existing proxy is the easiest thing but I'm not allowed access.
- Firewall, parental control in Antivirus ( I've tried just trend micro) and blocking from internet options all dont work.

Options:

- Having to install a software is OK.
- Any pointers to achieving this using some kind of scripting are OK. ( intercepting all GET/POST requests and rerouting on pattern matching)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7. just edited the question.

Comment: If you edit the hosts file to point such addresses to the localhost it should effectively block them.